# Facebook integration problem in android

Tags: android

I'm trying to integrate Facebook in my application.I've downloaded facebook sdk in my application and have added it in my project.But when i run my app i'm getting 
**java.lang.noclassdeffounderror com.facebook.android.**
facebookthis exception on following line

**Facebook facebook=new Facebook(App_id);**

can somebody tell me where i'm going wrong....

Answer (score 1):

In the APP_Id you have to insert your own application id of the application that you created on Facebook.
First you will have to create an application on Facebook, where you get the APP_ID and then use it.

Answer (score 0):

for example i have a facebook instance and than you authorize it:

```
        mFacebook = app.getFacebookInstance();
    if (!mFacebook.isSessionValid()) {
        mFacebook.authorize(this, new String[] { "friends_birthday", "friends_about_me", "read_friendlists" }, new DialogListener() {

            @Override
            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError arg0) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(DialogError arg0) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete(Bundle arg0) {

                getFriendsList();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {

            }
        });
    } else {
        getFriendsList();
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "session valid");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Facebook library can not be found at runtime.

In Eclipse, you can add it, via "project" > properties > Android. In the 'library' Window, click add and select your Facebook library project.

A clean build should be enough to make the NCDFE go away.

Comment: Bolmmaerts...thanx for ur ans...under library tab there are several tabs like add library,add exteral library etc...if i click add external jar it doesn't allow me to select my project..so where should i click ...please help..

Comment: You seem to have a different version from the one I've got installed on this system .. I have no tabs under library, but you should look for "library project" as you need to select the Facebook project you've configured yourself (Project selection). You don't have to select an external jar, you need to select a project.

Answer (score 0):

There are few tricks that should be done before successfully connect to Facebook.
You have to obtain your application hash code using the key tool app. But the key tool can return wrong hash code. You have to install OpenSSl and this is a bit difficult.

I week ago I view this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PEVEL1YTjI4) on You Tube.

This is a video how to setup this [application](http://codecanyon.net/item/android-startup-application-/243698) that can be bought from CodeCanyon.  The author connect with facebook in No time. I bought the app and I had my running facebook application in  5 min.